# Yii::app()->user->isAdmin() is not working properly in layout page

Tags: php, yii

in my layout page Cmenu visible fn `Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()` is not working properly when i use `Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()` in someother  view it showing correct value but not working in layout.
my code in protected/views/layouts/main.php

```
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index'),/*'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest*/),
            array('label'=>'Master','url'=>array('/site/master'),'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()),
            array('label'=>'Transaction','url'=>array('/site/transaction'),'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()),
            array('label'=>' Alotted Task','url'=>array('/site/alottedtask'),'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),    
            array('label'=>'Completed Task','url'=>array('/site/completedtask'),'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Status Update', 'url'=>array('/site/statusupdate'),'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()),

            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        ),
    )); ?>
```

it showing the error like

> Trying to get property of non-object

**Update:**

My error page `http://localhost/tracktest/index.php`

[image: error page]

Comment: Car you provide more detail on the `Trying to get property of non-object` error? Which property is causing the error (isAdmin? name? isGuest?) Also - did you add an `isAdmin()` method to your Application's `CWebUser` class? Please add the the `isAdmin()` method to your question

Comment: @thaddeusmt i added isAdmin() in my CWebUser.it working properly when i test the code after login.if i test the code when using as a guest its not working and giving the error i hope you understand what i am telling...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is the code that is throwing the "non-object" error:

```
return intval($user->role) == 1;
```

This means that when PHP is trying to get the `role` attribute of the `$user` object, `$user` is not actually an object. Looking at your code, this means that either `loadUser()` is not working correctly, or `Yii::app()->user->id` is not returning the user ID.

To test this, I would add this to your function so some test variables will be printed out:

```
function isAdmin() { // this should say "public function", btw
  $testId = Yii::app()->user->id;
  echo $testId;
  print_r(User::model()->findByPk($testId));
  die();
}
```

This should let you see if you are getting the user ID, and if the user if being loaded properly.

Good luck!

Comment: sorry for delayed reply i am not well for few days...yii::app()->user->id; returning id properly

Answer (score 3):

Use `Yii::app()->user->getName()=='username'` if you want to check for specific user.

Comment: it worked for me, and i replaced username wid admin to compare with and i got the functionality like isAdmin() which is suggested by some people above. This functionality is good if someone like me needs something inline instead of implementing a function by the name like isAdmin();

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`array('label' => 'Master', 'url' => array('/site/master'), 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess(array('admin')),`